# How to loop through monthly data with VBA?

Tags: vba

I am new here and will appreciate your help in the challenge I am facing.

I am working on a project using VBA for Excel. I have data from 14 months and want to divide the last value of every month by the first value of the same month. The first working day of the month can be any day, and so can the last day. I wrote the code below to find and highlight the last day of every month, and it works.

```
sub find_lastrow()
    Dim lrow As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim data As Date
    Dim next_day As Date

    lrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 2 To lrow

        data = Cells(i, "A")
        next_date = Cells(i, "A").Offset(1, 0)

        'finding and painting last day of each month and last day of each year

        If Month(next_date) = Month(data) + 1 Or _
            Year(next_date) = Year(data) + 1 Then

            Range(Cells(i, "A"), Cells(i, "K")).Select

            With Selection.Interior
                .Pattern = xlSolid
                .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorLight2
                .TintAndShade = 0.799981688894314
                .PatternTintAndShade = 0
            End With

        End If
End sub
```

However, I am having a hard time dividing the first value of each month by the last value of the corresponding month. I highly appreciate your help.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you need to finish your loop.  Secondly, to divide the last value by the first value, just create a variable to retain the first value until you reach the row containing the last row - then it is available for the division:

```
sub find_lastrow()
    Dim lrow As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim data As Date
    Dim next_day As Date
    Dim StartValue As Double

    lrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    StartValue = Cells(2, "B").Value

    For i = 2 To lrow

        data = Cells(i, "A")
        next_date = Cells(i + 1, "A")

        'finding and painting last day of each month and last day of each year

        If Month(next_date) = Month(data) + 1 Or _
            Year(next_date) = Year(data) + 1 Then

            Cells(i, "C").Value = Cells(i, "B").Value / StartValue
            'Set up start value for next month
            StartValue = Cells(i + 1, "B").Value

            With Range(Cells(i, "A"), Cells(i, "K")).Interior
                .Pattern = xlSolid
                .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorLight2
                .TintAndShade = 0.799981688894314
                .PatternTintAndShade = 0
            End With

        End If
    Next
End Sub
```